# Software for throttling CPU power (for certain processes)

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet-explorer, process-control, processes

I am looking for a software which can throttle the CPU power for certain processes. Especially for Internet Explorer and embedded ads in Adobe Flash.

Background: A customer, who is a translator, often needs a lot of pages to be open in Internet Explorer, but then the embedded flash ads are consuming a lot of CPU, letting the CPU fan go high, which is unnecessary. However, instead of closing always all pages, I would like to throttle the CPU power for process `iexplore.exe`

Comment: Maybe disabling Flash is an option? I've kicked Flash already several months ago and rarely miss it. Alternatively, one could block Flash using Firefox and an addon, so "essentials" could still be activated manually when needed (e.g. click the place-holder, confirm to "set this Flash object free" – or "allow Flash for this domain/page"). Would any of the two fit?

Comment: @Izzy Well, thanks for your comment -- I did this for myself in Firefox, but this customer has low computer affinitiy and it is too complicated. Also, some HTML pages do not render correctly with flash disabled, and recently some web pages complain that I have "installed an ad blocker" (which is not true - I only blocked Flash ;) )  - and they do not continue.

Comment: I'd personally say just boycott those sites (they're neither user-friendly nor up-to-date) – but I get your point, and it's not about politics here ;) I've got to pass it on then – but I see you've already got your solution, glad to see! (Though I don't see how that's easier to manage for that user; probably you'll set it up for him once and hope it fits for a while without needing adjustments? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend Bill2's Process manager.  You can create rules for processes which assign a priority level together with which cpu cores they are allowed to use.  I always limit flash to one core myself.

You can find it here http://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Downloaded it, this is a really cool tool.

Comment: Oh Rohit, had you posted that 15 mins earlier it had saved me a headache! At a customers site I have to work with Windows, and the most favorite program (read: AV scanner) blocked my machine at 100% CPU for more than an hour … +1, bookmarked, goes to that workbench tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

google chrome + ghostery addon/app  it is an ad blocker. that for most part completely shuts out all flash, java, misc analytic scripts, etc...  it also can block out facebook, and like little things that load up on many websites. (can be re-enabled if needed/wanted)

suggestion is go back through its settings and just disable everything, and disable the "pop-up" that it might show. ((three little bars)) top right corner -> settings -> extensions -> ghostery)) or enter chrome://extensions/ into address bar.

if i do not run ghostery, many websites i visit, will bring my computer to a slow crawl. and a few times a year end up with some flash hack attempt that causes browser to crash.  as long as i keep ghostery going i do not experience any issues. and rare occasions 10 plus windows and 30 plus tabs opened. when i go on a research binge.

=================

google search for one of the following. to bring up better direct "picture tutorials.

disable flash internet explorer
disable flash chrome
disable flash firefox

i still have flash enabled, and for a couple websites require it.  it is all the advertisements, analytical stuff. that crushes things.

===================

IE explorer over all... generally statement is forget about it, and just switch over to google chrome or firefox browser.